# How to use MySQL value ins second query?

Tags: mysql, union

How can I do this:

```
SELECT Board_id FROM topic WHERE Value1='".$value2."' UNION SELECT Name FROM Boards WHERE Id=Board_id
```

Should I use `UNION`? Or should I use two different queries? What is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join:

```
select name, board_id from boards b inner join topic t on t.board_id=b.id
where t.value1='VALUE1'
```

See a SQL join tutorial on W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Note, if you're using PHP, your code is at risk of SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

There are a number of ways to protect against this:

```
$sql = "SELECT board_id, name from boards b inner join topic t on " .
   " t.board_id=b.id " .
   " where t.value1='" . mysql_real_escape_string($value2) . "'";
```

Better yet might be to use a parameterized query, but this depends on whether you're using PHP's MySQL or MySQLi libraries.

Comment: Is it faster to do it this way, or is a second query better?

Comment: You want the database to do the work it is designed to do, so if you've got an index on topic.board_id and boards.id (which is presumably your primary key), this is probably the fastest way - depending on the db implementation, the other ways might be as fast.

Comment: Just another observation, if you're using PHP, your code is at risk of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Board_id, B.Name FROM topic t
left join Boards B ON (B.id = t.Board_id)
where t.SELECT Board_id FROM topic = $value1
```

Comment: Is it faster to do it this way, or is a second query better?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Name FROM Boards WHERE Id = (SELECT Board_id FROM topic WHERE Value1='".$value2."')`

Comment: Is it faster to do it this way, or is a second query better?

Comment: One query is usually a better idea as compared to using two different queries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Boards 
WHERE Id
    = ( SELECT Board_id 
         FROM topic 
         WHERE Value1 =  $value2
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you left join the Boards table using the IDs as follows:

```
SELECT topic.Board_id, Boards.name 
FROM topic 
LEFT JOIN Boards 
ON topic.Board_id = Boards.id 
WHERE topic.Value1='".$value2."'
```